# Efficient/easy way to guard for NULL after conversion from "char x[n]" to "char* x"?

Tags: c

I have recently made changes in some code that makes a `char name` field dynamic.

So it was originally like

```
struct boo 
{
    char name[100];
    ...
}
```

and i have changed it to

```
struct boo
{
    char *name;
    ...
}
```

so this make name dynamically allocate the amount of memory actually needed to store the names.

Anyway.. the result of this change will require me to add `if(boo->name)` null pointer check in about 1000 places in the code.

So just wondering is there any smart or efficient way (reduce programmer development time) of doing this null pointer check.

Comment: Whats wrong with a simple `if(name)`, it is always guaranteed to work.However, strongly advice you to get rid of the `char *` and use `std::string` that will save you a lot of unwanted trouble.

Comment: Efficiency of what? Run-time speed? Or programmer development time?

Comment: Adding null pointer checks in a 1000 places sounds like a bad idea to begin with.

Comment: (Please tag *with only one of*: C C++ C#)

Comment: @Mysticial programmer development time

Comment: @Als: The question is tagged C; `std::string` is C++.

Comment: @user1462755: This should be about how you design your code. Bail out as early as you can. Your contract for sections of the code dealing with `boo::name` should require that it is non-null. It may or may not be trivial to implement though.

Comment: @dirkgently: The tag on this Q has been changed *after* i posted the comment.It was tagged C++.

Comment: @Als: Aha! Let us await the OP's comments.

Comment: @Als and dirkgently: ya sorry about, tagged C++ and then removed it after 2 mins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be far easier to ensure that the buffer is allocated when the structure is created rather than checking it wherever the structure is used. Don't ever let it be NULL in the first place!

If you need a pointer value to place in the structure before you have the relevant data, you can keep a global empty string to use specifically for this task. Compare to this pointer before trying to `free` the memory.

If this is C++ and not C, seriously consider using a `std::string` instead of a pointer.

Comment: +1 for answering not what he asked, but what he should have asked.

Answer (score 1):

if (name) works, but there is always the problem that your pointer may not be initialized to NULL to start with.

if you are dynamically allocating your structs, to make sure this happens, do:

```
mystruct foo = calloc(sizeof(foo));
```

calloc zeroes the memory.

EDIT:
In addition, if you only want to check for name in debug builds, you can do:

```
assert(name);
```

This will quit the program right at that line if name is NULL but be optimized out to nothing in "release" builds.

Comment: Nitpick: calloc zeroes the memory, but that doesn't guarantee that the pointer will be NULL, since the C standard allows the internal representation of NULL to be something else than all bits zero.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy yeah...I know. I always say that, and it's true, but it's practically an unwritten part of the standard... :-P

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is to check the return allocation succeeds when you `malloc`.

Some people like to use the `xmalloc` wrapper to `malloc` from `libiberty` library:

> — Replacement: void* xmalloc (size_t)
>   Allocate memory without fail. If malloc fails, this will print a message to stderr (using the name set by xmalloc_set_program_name, if any) and then call xexit. Note that it is therefore safe for a program to contain #define malloc xmalloc in its source.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libiberty/Functions.html

You can also easily write your own `xmalloc` function:

```
void *xmalloc(size_t size)
{
    char *p = malloc(size);

    if (!p) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Error: allocation failure\n");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }        

    return p;
}
```